# How can I create instances of customized builtins?

Tags: javascript, dom, custom-element, native-web-component

I'm writing a JSX factory for vanilla JS, but **I can't seem to get customized builtins to work.**

If I define a

```js
customElements.define('x-hi', class extends HTMLElement { })
```

I can just

```js
document.createElement('x-hi')
```

to get an instance, how can I get an instance of this :-

```js
customElements.define('x-hello', class extends HTMLButtonElement { }, { extends: 'button' })
```

Comment: Note this will never work in Safari, because Apple has stated (for 5 years now) it won't implement _**Customized Built-In**_ Elements. So only ``class extends HTMLElement`` (**Autonomous Elements**) will work cross browser.

Comment: @danny-365csi-engelman This is for an Electron app, don't worry

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
class Hello extends HTMLButtonElement { }
customElements.define('x-hello', Hello, { extends: 'button' });
new (customElements.get('x-hello'))() instanceof Hello
// --> true
```

You can also do it with normal custom elements, but you should use `document.createElement` as the custom element may be defined later on in the code.

You're probably doing something like this in your factory:

```js
const el = document.createElement(tagName);
for (let attrName in attrs) el.setAttribute(attrName, attrs[attrName]);
```

When setting `is` to `x-hello` on an already created `HTMLButtonElement`, you can't change it's prototype to have it become a `Hello`